# i want to play multiple mp3 in order jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, mp3

I want to create a script in javascript/jquery that play's/speaks the letters of a certain word in the background.

when i call the function playWord(); It spells out the letters of a word in a div.

For example, the word 'help'. It should spell: 'h'  'e'  'l'  'p'. Each letter has an .mp3 file.

Before the next letter spells, it has to wait untill the letter is fully spelled.

This is what i have so far, but its not properly. Sometimes the time in between letters is like 5 seconds.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

var letterCounter = 0;
//the letter speed in ms
var spellAudioSpeed = 1000;

function playWord(){
    letterCounter = 0;
    //the word from the div
    playLetters($('#transWord').text().toLowerCase());
}

function playLetters(pWord){
    if(letterCounter < pWord.length){

        var letter = pWord.charAt(letterCounter);
        //create an new audio element
        var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');

        if(letter == ' '){
            audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'Letters/spatie.mp3');
        } else if(letter == '\''){
            audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'Letters/aanhalingsteken.mp3');
        } else if(letter == '\\"'){
            audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'Letters/dubbeleaanhalingsteken.mp3');
        } else if(letter == '/'){
            audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'Letters/schuinestreep.mp3');
        } else if(letter == '\\'){
            audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'Letters/schuinestreepachteruit.mp3');
        } else {
            audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'Letters/'+letter+'.mp3');
        }

        //couldnt find a better way to determine the duration.. ???
        audioElement.addEventListener('durationchange', function() {
            audioElement.play();
            letterCounter++;
            timeOut = setTimeout(function(){playLetters(pWord)},
            spellAudioSpeed + (audioElement.duration * 1000));
        }, true);

    } else if (letterCounter == pWord.length){
        //do stuff
        alert("finished");
    }
}

playWord();
```

Comment: Did you try preloading the sound files?

Comment: You are right, if you put this in the answer section, i will mark it as Correct answer. Thanks :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the [preload](http://www.quackit.com/html_5/tags/html_audio_tag.cfm) attribute.